# Chaining a compiled query's invocation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Suppose I have a compiled query that hits the DB and does a select.

```
    Func<MyContext, int, IQueryable<MyResult>> myQuery = 
CompiledQuery.Compile<MyContext, int, IQueryable<Employee>>((context, empId) =>
      (ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == empId));
```

and then I do

```
myQuery.Invoke(ctx, paramA).orderby(x => x.someColumn).Take(10).ToList();
```

Will the orderby be done in-memory (i.e the query to the context contains only myQuery) or will the `Invoke` chain 'myQuery' with the orderby and toList() so the order and take is done in the DB.
I believe it is the latter. Am I right?

Comment: So, if you are returning an IQueryable then you will be working against the database. Which means it won't be pulled to memory until you iterate of the collection.

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation! I was not sure because of the Invoke(), whether it would cause a db hit immediately. So, in this case it will hit the db only due to the `ToList()`

Comment: The func might return an IQueryable but it is not clear that this is a live EF query. Could be an in-memory query. Test this with SQL Profiler.